# How do I fix EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to join a massive server the minecraft client crashes with this error: `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. Anyone know how to fix this? Here's my log: http://pastebin.com/9DL7ybc4 This is not a duplicite because it is only when I join a server.

Answer (score 0):

One of your mods seem to be causing a problem:

```
Caused by: fc: Error while parsing: TranslatableComponent{key='Ranks Sale §c50% Off!§r'...
```

Try disabling the mod **KingRay111's Sword Pack**

Comment: Just note that because you're obviously running mods on your Minecraft client, this basically makes the question off topic immediately.  If you're having trouble with the mod, contact the mod creator.

Comment: I disabled the texture pack and it is still crashing with the same error.

Comment: Re-install the game, start a single player server, etc.  Go through the steps to get a working, vanilla Minecraft, then start adding stuff (multiplayer, different servers, mods, etc).  I'm pretty sure Minecraft worked for you at one point.

Comment: I tried to reinstall the game but it didn't work...